# MySQL Workbench export data and import it to the schema with different name

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

When I export my remote database to a folder using MySQL Workbench, how can I remove the comment about `Database` name?

The problem is, when the table is exported, this comment is added to the top:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.9, for osx10.9 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: somehosturl.amazonaws.com    Database: somedb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.27-log
...
```

Therefore, Workbench thinks the schema must be `somedb` and doesn't let me change it when I want to import it.

[image: Default Target Schema chooser]

Can I somehow prevent adding these lines during export?

**EDIT:**

I have just removed all of these lines and workbench doesn't recognize any schema nor let me choose one. So the question is how to export structure and date from a schema and import it do the different one with different name.

Comment: I usually just edit the `USE database_name;` in the file before importing it

Comment: I export to the folder so each table has it's own sql file and the Workbench UI doesn't allow me to import it to different schema

Comment: So export to a self contained file and then edit the `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` lines

Comment: The database is very huge and if I export each table to a single file, I can avoid aborting the whole upload when it fails. I can choose what tables to import in this way

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem. Did you find any solution? @simPod

Comment: Hi, no, I'm not using mysql for few years now

Answer (score -2):

I exported as a project via Workbench 6.

I imported it in 2 steps:

1. The export files were prefixed with the database name. I renamed the prefix to the new database name.
2. After that I opened the files and did a search on the old database name and replaced it with the new database it.

Comment: How do you do that on production databases that might have xxx+ GBs in size?

Comment: @simPod, the question is how to do it and not how to do it with xxx+ GB. Perhaps create a new question or search more.